# Wordpress: Seleting a custom post taxonomy term based on custom field meta key value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for any info regarding automatically selecting a *taxonomy* based on a meta key value being '`true/false`' after *save/update* of a custom post.

E.g., I have two *taxonomy* terms, '`New`' and '`Used`'. I have a custom field checkbox for the custom post '`vehicle listings`'. I am looking for the best function to dynamically assign the right *taxonomy* term based on the `true` or `false` value of the checkbox (`true` = Used, `false` = New) after `save` or `update` of the post. Would this be better as a function?

Answer (score 0):

You should add custom function to save_post hook which checks custom field value and set term value based on this. F.e.

```
 function save_cp_term_meta( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
        $termshouldbe='termfalse';

        //if true checked
        if ( isset( $_POST['vehicle_listing'] ) and $_POST['vehicle_listing'] ==1) {
          $termshouldbe='termtrue';
        }

        wp_set_object_terms($post_id,$termshouldbe,'taxonomy_name',false);
    }
    add_action( 'save_post', 'save_cp_term_meta', 10, 3 );
```